# Transforma um campo no formulário obrigatório quando select selecionado sim

Tags: php, javascript, html, formulário

Tenho um campo no meu formulário em PHP onde pergunto se o usuário tem telefone em casa. É um select com SIM e NÃO. Caso seja SIM o campo a seguir tem que ser obrigatório o preenchimento, caso negativo, o campo não será obrigatório.

```
   <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
<label for="telcasa"> Telefone de Casa:</label>  
<select required name="telcasa" required  class="form-control" id="telcasa">
    <option value="escolhaopcao">Selecione</option>
    <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
    <option value="Não">Não</option>
  </select>
 </div>   

 <div class="col-sm-8 form-group">
                                    <label for="telefone_casa">Caso sua resposta seja sim, deixe o número aqui: </label>
                                    <input name="telefone_casa" type="number" required class="form-control" id="telefone_casa" maxlength="50">
                                </div>
```

Como faço essa regra funcionar? Se a seleção for SIM o campo Caso sua resposta seja sim, deixe o número aqui: ficará obrigatório, caso Não, ele não será obrigatório.

Segue imagem dos campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da para fazer com JS puro de forma bem simples, se o `value` do `Select` for `nao`, vc remove o atributo `require` do `input`

Pelo CSS eu coloquei uma bordar vermelho nos campos com `require`, então quando vc escolher `NÃO` a borda vai sumir, pq vai remover o atributo `require` do `input`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
let sel = document.getElementById('telcasa');

function verifica() {
    let nao = document.getElementById('telefone_casa');
    if (sel.value == 'nao') {
        nao.required = false;
    } else {
        nao.required = true;
    }
}

sel.addEventListener('change', verifica);
```

```css
:required {
  border:2px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
            <label for="telcasa"> Telefone de Casa:</label>
            <select required name="telcasa" required class="form-control" id="telcasa">
                <option value="escolhaopcao">Selecione</option>
                <option value="sim">Sim</option>
                <option value="nao">Não</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8 form-group">
            <label for="telefone_casa">Caso sua resposta seja sim, deixe o número aqui: </label>
            <input name="telefone_casa" type="number" required class="form-control" id="telefone_casa" maxlength="50">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito irmão, mas aqui para mim não funcionou! No dreamweaver dá uma mensagem de erro, There is a syntax error on line 23: Code hinting may not work until you fix this error. Essa linha 23 é esse codigo: let sel = document.getElementById('telcasa');

Comment: @AlessandroRamos não tem porque não funcionar, vc conferiu se o ID do elemento é esse mesmo ou vc mudou o nome do ID? Não tem porque não funcionar no VS Code não acusa erro algum, e aqui no site funciona perfeitamente, então foi vc que mudou algo ai que fez o código parar de funcionar. Inclusive se vc pegar meu código e testar localmente em um arquivo seu separado muito provavelmente tb não vai apresentar erros, copia e cola a resposta em um HTML novo e testa

Comment: Valeu irmão, deu certo!!!!

Comment: @AlessandroRamos ai sim, não tinha pq não funcionar rss

Answer (score 0):

**Para o `select`, o segredo é esta option `<option value="">Selecione</option>`
    Como você adicionou o atributo required no select, então, a primeira 
    option deve ter o seu `value` igual a "";**
    
Ou
    É só adicionar o valor do primeiro option igual a `""`;

**Como você pediu na questão, usando `JQuery`:**

> Tente este código:

```js
$("#telcasa").change(function(){

 let _this =  this;

 if(_this.selectedIndex == 1){

$("#telefone_casa").attr("required",true);

}
else{

$("#telefone_casa").removeAttr("required");

}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<label for="telcasa"> Telefone de Casa:</label>  
<select required name="telcasa" required  class="form-control" id="telcasa">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
    <option value="Não">Não</option>
  </select>
 </div>   

 <div class="col-sm-8 form-group">
                                    <label for="telefone_casa">Caso sua resposta seja sim, deixe o número aqui: </label>
                                    <input name="telefone_casa" type="number" required class="form-control" id="telefone_casa" maxlength="50">
                                </div>
```

> Tenta este exemplo:

https://repl.it/@TaffarelXavier/LatestAustereEfficiency

Comment: Oi amigo, obrigado pelo contato, não deu certo :(

Comment: O que está aparecendo? O que você realmente quer?

Comment: Então amigo, com a seleção do NÃO o campo do telefone_casa ainda continua sendo obrigatório o preenchimento. Deveria ser liberado, conforme a função que vc me enviou, correto? Será que tenho que remover o "required" dessa linha: <input name="telefone_casa" type="number" required class="form-control" id="telefone_casa" maxlength="50">

Comment: Na verdade, se você estiver usando o JQuery, isso já é feito automaticamente, conforme eu descrevi no código que mandei.

Comment: Foi o que imaginei

Comment: https://repl.it/@TaffarelXavier/LatestAustereEfficiency